# Objective C Abandoned Memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, heap-memory, abandoned-memory

I have a question about abandoned memory using View Controllers.

I have a Navigation Bar button that presents another Navigation Controller.  Everything works well, but when I run an a Generation Analysis, there seems to be abandon memory related to the newTransaction method below.  It'll show in two of my first snapshots, but then it'll show zero growth going forward.  I guess my question is, I am presenting the controller correctly (I'm using ARC), or should I be changing the way I present the controller?

```
#pragma mark - Nav bar button actions

- (void)newTransaction
{
    NewTransactionTableViewController *  transactionController = [[NewTransactionTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    transactionController.transactionDelegate = self;
    UINavigationController * addTransactionNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:transactionController];
    [self presentViewController:addTransactionNavController animated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)dismissNewTransactionView //Delegate Method
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: How is the transactionDelegate property declared?

Comment: It's defined weak, nonatomic